# mdot Analog in: how to connect Grove temperature sensor?

Tags: arm, stm32, mbed

I am starting with multitech [mdot product](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/MTS-mdot-f411/).

I am confused about how can I use the mdot pin PB_1 (linked to A0 in UDK) to read my [Grove temperature sensor](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Temperature_and_Humidity_Sensor) value.
Is it enough to simply connect it to the sensor signal output or should I configure the microprocessor ADC to be able to use the pin PB_1 as an analog Input?

in the [developer guide](http://www.multitech.com/manuals/s000612_1_6.pdf) page 21 the pin described as: PB_1/AD0/DIO0

what does this description mean?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Your Grove temperature sensor is made to be connected to an ADC input of your microprocessor.
Then you need to configure your microprocessor to use an ADC pin, and convert the voltage in input in a data by softawre.
So, pin described as "PB_1/AD0/DIO0" means that the same pin as three distinct function that can be used : PB number 1, ADC number 0, and Digital input/outpu number 0. But you can only use one function at a time by configuring it by software.

Regards,

Comment: thanks for your response :) could you recommand me a tutorial that I can follow to be able to configure my microprocessor to use an ADC pin and to read the data?

Comment: To configure correctly your microprocessor, you have to look in the datasheet of it. Some part will speak about hardware characteritic and some other part will speak about software configuration and functions. Or you can use google with your microprocessor reference and what you want to do. Example : mymicro configuring ADC pin.

Comment: I think you have to explore documents quote page 7 in chapter Programming the mDot Microcontroller or in chapter Related Documentation. I can't be more precise.

Regards,